# Specializing a method that takes type parameters

Tags: scala

I want to write code that has a generic, possibly slow, implementation of a type parameterized method that works for all classes implementing a certain interface but still allow for subclasses to specialize this method with more efficient implementations if they so desire.

However, the following code does not quite work

```
class A(val i:Int)

class B {
    def f[T](t:T) = println(t.toString)
}

class C extends B { 
    override def f[A](a:A) = println(a.i * a.i) 
}
```

because it treats A in class C as a type parameter not as something that overrides the function for the case where the type parameter is only A.

Is there a way to write the code that I want without using match at runtime?

Comment: no, there's isn't. What's wrong with pattern matching?

Comment: Apart from being uglier in this case pattern matching would force all bits of code to explicitly fall back to the superclass's method if they can't match, which is a lot of redundant code to write all over the place.

Comment: you don't have to write that code all over the place, just use a template method:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Answer (score 0):

What you're going for is this:

```
scala> class A(val i: Int)
defined class A

scala> class B { 
     |   def f[T](t: T) = println(t.toString)
     | }
defined class B

scala> class C extends B { 
     |   override def f[T <: A](a: T) = println(a.i * a.i) 
     | }
<console>:10: error: overriding method f in class B of type [T](t: T)Unit;
 method f has incompatible type
         override def f[T <: A](a: T) = println(a.i * a.i)
```

But as the type system tells you, this is **wrong**. You are violating the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) here.

What you can instead do is make `T` a class level type parameter or an abstract type member. Then you can constrain it in the subclasses as shown below:

```
scala> class B {
     |   type T
     |   def f(t: T) = println(t.toString)
     | }
defined class B

scala> class C extends B {
     |   type T = A
     |   override def f(a: T) = println(a.i * a.i)
     | }
defined class C

scala> (new C).f(new A(11))
121
```

You haven't provided more information so I don't know if this will work in your particular case or not.

**Edit:**

Here's one way to speciailize things: using typeclasses. Code: (This turned out to be more convoluted than expected.)

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

case class A(i: Int)

case object B

trait F[-A] {
  def f(a: A): Unit
}

trait FLowPriorityImplicits {
  implicit object FAny extends F[Any] {
    def f(a: Any) = println(a.toString)
  }
}

trait FImplicits extends FLowPriorityImplicits {
  implicit object FA extends F[A] {
    def f(a: A) = println(a.i * a.i)
  }
}

object F extends FImplicits

def f[A](x: A)(implicit f: F[A]) = f.f(x)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class A
defined module B
defined trait F
defined trait FLowPriorityImplicits
defined trait FImplicits
defined module F
f: [A](x: A)(implicit f: F[A])Unit

scala> f(B)
B

scala> f(A(2))
4
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work because I'd like it to be possible for a single subclass to override the method for more than one different type parameter.

Comment: That is not possible. Did you read about the Liskov Substitution Principle?

Comment: Also this doesn't quite violate the substitution principle if you think of a generic method as being a collection of methods, one for each possible type parameter, which are lazily instantiated. Then overriding a few of these methods is not necessarily wrong. Let's say you're writing a linear algebra package, for example, and instead of f[T] we have f[T <: Vector], but we might want subclasses to work efficiently with both SparseVector and DenseVector, but not always have to do that.

Comment: Method arguments are contravariant positions. You can widen the type there, not narrow it. This is how LSP works.

Comment: I'm not talking about narrowing the type of the method, just overriding the method for some types, using the other implementation for the other types.

Comment: That _is_ narrowing. Typeclasses might suit your problem better than subtyping. I will edit my answer later and expand on that.

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't quite solve the problem but you've convinced me I need to rethink this design.

Comment: @AlexandrePassos, glad to have been of some help.